# WPF: Get MouseEnter Event When IsEnabled=false

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, mouseevent

I want to handle MouseEnter event for a Custom Control when control is disabled.
Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`UIElement.IsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) documents the behaviour you see:

> Elements that are not enabled do not participate in hit testing or focus and therefore will not be sources of input events.

The logical conclusion, to me, is that if you do want to handle mouse events, you don't disable the control. Instead, use some other method of achieving what you want. For example, if it's an input control, it may be good enough to make it read-only instead of disabled. Your question doesn't really explain why you want this, so I cannot guess what the right method for you will be.

Comment: Actually my problem is setting a new ToolTip when mouse entered the control. I observed that tooltip can popup even if the control is disabled (without content) because of `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled` property. How can catch mouse enter?

Comment: @pilavust The control doesn't handle that itself. It can't, because it's not getting the event. It seems to be indirectly coming from [`InputManager.Current.PostProcessInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmanager.postprocessinput(v=vs.110).aspx). But perhaps [`ToolTipService.AddToolTipOpeningHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.addtooltipopeninghandler.aspx) would be a better choice for you?

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you could surround your custom control with a `ContentControl` (which must always be enabled) and handle `MouseEnter` event on the `ContentControl`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not change control structure. My goal is only simulate the MouseEnter event.